# Existence of a double integral

Tags: calculus

Let's define $f$ as a function from $[0,1]^2$ to the real numbers as:

$$f(x,y) = 1 \hspace{3mm} if x \in Q \\
f(x,y) = 2y \hspace{3mm} if x \notin Q$$

Prove that $\int_{0}^{1} dx \int_{0}^{1} dy f(x,y)$ exists (I know how to do it) but $\int_{0}^{1} dy \int_{0}^{1} dx f(x,y)$ doesn't (that's where I get lost). I don't know why the argument used for the existence of the first integral doesn't work for the second one. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you talking about riemann or lesbesgues integrals?

Comment: Riemann still; sorry for not specifying it.

Comment: Ok. For lesbegues they would both exist rather trivially.

Comment: Note, that f is countinous in y for a fixed x. Hence the inner integral in the first case always exists, it is easy to verify, that it equals one.So you are just integrating one in the outer integral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second case, f is neither continous, nor monotonous in x for almost every y. In fact it is nowhere continous in x for y$\neq$ 0.5 and therefore not riemann integrabel by the riemann-lebesgue-theorem.
The outer integral is now over a function that is defined only on 0.5 and thus also doesnt exist.